# Getting rid of null / space characters in pyspark

Tags: python, regex, apache-spark, pyspark

I have leading and trailing characters in a pyspark dataframe. But trim and `regex_replace` doesn't seem to work for them. There are probably some null unicode characters. My questions are

1. How do I identify those characters? (copying and pasting just copies a blank space)
2. Is there a way to get rid of them

These are the steps, I have taken so far

```
df = df.withColumn("email", F.encode(F.col("email"), "UTF-8"))
df = df.withColumn("email", F.regexp_replace(F.col("email"), " ", ""))
df = df.withColumn("email", F.regexp_replace(F.col("email"), "\u0000", ""))
df = df.withColumn("email", F.trim(F.col("email")))
df = df.withColumn("length", F.length(F.col("email")))
df.select("email", "length").display()
```

This is the output
[image]

PS: When I try to copy a string and do a strip using python, it gets rid of the whitespace

```
" Kaliyah@cool.com".strip()
# 'Kaliyah@cool.com'
```

and making a udf out of this also works

```
def strip(value):
    return value.strip()

stripUdf = F.udf(strip, T.StringType())
```

But I don't want to use this because of performance issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could instead try the opposite approach where you remove any symbol that is *not* an alphanumeric character or the symbols `.` and `@`. For example:

```
df.withColumn(
    "clean_email", F.regexp_replace(F.col("email"), "[^A-Za-z0-9\.\@]", "")
).withColumn(
    "clean_email_length", F.length('clean_email')
)

+----------------+--------------+------------------+
|           email|   clean_email|clean_email_length|
+----------------+--------------+------------------+
|  abc@gmail.com | abc@gmail.com|                13|
| bcd@email.org� | bcd@email.org|                13|
|abcd@gmail.com□ |abcd@gmail.com|                14|
+----------------+--------------+------------------+
```